# How to enqueue default scripts with dependency?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-dependencies

I'm developing a plugin and for that I need jQuery and jQuery datepicker. I's taught that WordPress [already enqueued some scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress), and I found 'jquery' and 'jquery-ui-datepicker' there.

Where the datepicker is said to be dependent to jQuery. In that codex page it's also mentioned that, we can call a dependent script like the following:

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', plugins_url( '/js/custom_script.js' , __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );
}    
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

I got the point is right for any custom script. But what about the default scripts?
**What to put on the source (`$src`) then?**

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker', $src, array( 'jquery' ) );
```

I can't put a null string (`''`) or a variable, anything, theoretically, and practically.

Comment: Just use `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );` if it's a core supplied script. You don't need to tell it anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to provide source or dependencies, they're already registered by the script loader with those values, you just need to enqueue the proper handle.